# Change of Variable for an Integral

Tags: integration

I have the following integral:

> $$ \int_{0}^{\tau} dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1} dt_2 \; \text{Tr} \langle B(t_1) B(t_2) \chi \rangle \times [F(t_2)\rho, F(t_1)], $$

where $F, B, \chi$ and $\rho$ are operators, $\text{Tr}$ denotes the trace and $[...]$ denotes the commutator.

If I make the change of variable

> $$ t' = t_1 - t_2 \quad \quad t_1 > t_2 , $$

the correct answer is

> $$ \int_{0}^{\tau} dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1} dt' \; \text{Tr} \langle B(t') B(0) \chi \rangle \times [F(t_1 - t')\rho, F(t_1)]. $$

Shouldn't I pick up a minus sign since

> $$ dt' = - \; dt_2. $$

Where's another minus sign coming from to cancel this minus sign. I'm sure this has something to do with the expression in $\langle ... \rangle $ but I'm not so sure how.

This may be a very elementary question but I'd appreciate if someone could answer it.

Comment: Because of the limits of the integral. When $t_2=0$, $t'= t_1$.

Comment: @peterag Doesn't this explain the change from our getting $\langle B(t')B(0) \rangle$ instead of $\langle B(t_1)B(t_2) \rangle$ in the expression? I have been making the same manipulation, but I don't know how this produces an extra minus sign.

Comment: actually - I had ignored the expression in the trace, because I thought you might have a typo or there was missing info - so I am signing off here.... sorry if I am no help!

Comment: All right. Anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

peter a g is right; the sign is from the reversal of the limits. Another way to remember this is that the factor from substitution is always the absolute value of the derivative, because if the derivative is negative the limits have to be swapped.

The change from $B(t_1)B(t_2)$ to $B(t_1-t_2)B(0)$ can't be explained on the basis of what you've told us alone; I suspect that the expression that this is a part of is known to be invariant under time translations, so you can subtract $t_2$ from both arguments; this most likely has nothing to do with the sign incurred by the substitution.

Comment: Yes, the expression is invariant under time translations. This is what motivated the change of variable in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the sign is from the reversal of the limits." The limits of integration are the same both before and after making the substitution. I don't get where the additional minus is coming from. If you, or anyone else, can write the details, that'd be great.

Comment: @JunaidAftab: The lower and upper limits for $t_2$ are $0$ and $t_1$, respectively. The corresponding values of $t'=t_1-t_2$ are $t_1-0=t_1$ and $t_1-t_1=0$, respectively. Thus, the lower and upper limits are swapped, and you get a minus sign when you swap them back.

Comment: @JunaidAftab: If that's not clear, perhaps it's easier to see in a simple example. E.g., $\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx$, with the substitution $u=1-x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the detail I was missing. Such a stupid error on my part. Thanks